# How to restrict the pass by reference default behaviour

Tags: c#

How to restrict the pass by reference behaviour of c# ? I don't want to change the original value of global variable,but it changed when it is assigned to a local variable and if any changes done to the local variable,it also affected the global variable.How to avoid this?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Show us the code and given/wanted behavior. As it is now, the question is unclear.

Comment: Actually, parameters in C# are usually passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: You have to specify "ref" or "out" if you want different behavior.

Comment: Are you looking for the C++ const for parameters?

Comment: This default behaviour you are talking about is the way the language works, it's not something you can change, your code has to change. If you have a reference type parameter in your method, don't assign anything to it when you only want to effect the local scope. Create a new object in the local scope of the method to interact with / change instead. Essentially for reference types, only read data from them if you don't want that object to change outside of the current scope.

Comment: Passing objects in general means editing that object in the passed-in function will edit the object. Here is an article that adds more clarity: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: If you need copy-by-value semantics and you have control over the type you're passing, then you can make it a `struct` instead of a class. Else, you would need to clone that object.

Answer (score 1):

In C# all parameters passed as value by default - copy of original value.
For reference types copied value is reference(memory address) of given object.

So obviously your global variable is a reference type. Where changing fields/properties inside method will have affect on the original value.
Consider examples below:

First example - changing a member

```
public void HandleObject(MyType value)
{
    value.Member = 5;
}

public void Main()
{
    MyType value = new MyType { Member = 3 };

    Console.WriteLine(value.Member);
    HandleObject(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value.Member);

    //Will print
    // 3
    // 5
}
```

First example - creating a new instance will not have affect

```
public void HandleObject(MyType value)
{
    value = new MyType { Member = 5 };
}

public void Main()
{
    MyType value = new MyType { Member = 3 };

    Console.WriteLine(value.Member);
    HandleObject(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value.Member);

    //Will print
    // 3
    // 3
}
```

So in your case you can create a copy of your global object and pass a copy to the method.